# How to handle telerik radalert box by selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, telerik

I am automating a website in which clicking on a button, a rad alert Message box open with a specific message and contains OK and cancel button.
I try to implement code as:
Alert al=driver.switchTo().alert();
al.accept();

After running code, In console throws an error as "No Alert Open"
Please Help me

Comment: Can you post the URL or screenshot of alert message.

Comment: When are you getting the error? its not closing the alert right?

Comment: When i used to click button i get alert pop up message and By Alert code, driver unable to find the Alert pop up Message

Comment: Then its not the alert.

Comment: Please post the URL here

Comment: @Pradeephebbar , sry can't paste URL. It is against company policy